# Cut out while driving

Tags: starting, hyundai, intermittent-problems, getz

Hyundai Getz, 2006. Having problem with the vehicle, first it would start and I would drive a long distance.  When switching the car off and want to start again, no go.  Soon after that I can start the vehicle after a short drive it would cut out and not start again.  Vehicle then have to be towed back.  what can the problem be.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does it continue to cut out after short distances? If so, have the fuel pump checked. Often when they start to go out, they become intermittent and the vehicle will only run for a little bit once you get it started. And when I suggest this, I'm assuming you can *attempt* to start the car, as in, you turn the key and the motor goes around and around, but it doesn't actually start. Is that correct?

Comment: After you check the fuel pump and fuel relay, check out the fuel regulator and fuel pressure